# How to remove blur view for Parent View but not the Child View?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4, uivisualeffectview

I am trying to add blur effect in view(Parent View) but not in its subView(Child View).

Does anyone knows how to remove blur effect from child view so that the blur effect remains in parent view?

Your time and help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If possible add your code or screen shots for better understanding

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri's idea sounds great. If you can't implement that for some reasons you may need to use delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably in the order that you add your views to the parent. You might be doing this right now.

- Add the parent view
- Add the child view
- Add the blur view

Instead try this

- Add the parent view
- Add the blur view on top of it
- Then add the child view.